# Resizing UITextView and UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uitextview, xcode5

I have new to objective C programming and i am currently trying to develop an iOS app. I am loading comment from the server onto the `UITextView` in the `UITableViewCell`.

This is the code that is used to load data into the UITextview.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath {
  // set the location to read the sample data
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CommentCell";
  CommentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CommentCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

PostModel *posts;
CommentModel *comments;
if (contentTitle == nil) {
    posts = _feed.posts[articleIndexPath.section];
    comments = posts.comments[indexPath.section];
}
else {
    posts = _feed.posts[searchResult];
    comments = posts.comments[indexPath.section];
}

NSString *content = comments.content;
content = [content stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<p>" withString:@""];
content = [content stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</p>" withString:@""];
cell.usernameLabel.text = comments.name;
[cell.commentTextView setScrollEnabled:YES];
cell.commentTextView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
cell.commentTextView.text = content;
[cell.commentTextView sizeToFit];
[cell.commentTextView setScrollEnabled:NO];
[cell.commentTextView setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[cell.usernameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

// make the borders of the cell round
[cell.layer setCornerRadius:7.0f];
[cell.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:51/255 green:56/255 blue:67/255 alpha:1] CGColor];

//make the borders of the image round
[cell.userImage.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[cell.userImage.layer setCornerRadius:7.0f];

return cell;
}
```

This is the code that i used to resize the `UITableViewCell` and `UITextView`

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CommentCell";
CommentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
PostModel *posts;
CommentModel *comments;
if (contentTitle == nil) {
    posts = _feed.posts[articleIndexPath.section];
    comments = posts.comments[indexPath.section];
}
else {
    posts = _feed.posts[searchResult];
    comments = posts.comments[indexPath.section];
};

if (cell.commentTextView.textContainer.size.height >= 40) {
    float height = [self heightForTextView:cell.commentTextView containingString:comments.content];
    return height;
}
else {
    return 79;
   }
}
```

This is the method that i used to detect the height of the text

```
- (CGFloat)heightForTextView:(UITextView *)textView containingString:(NSString *)string {
float horizontalPadding = 8;
float verticalPadding = 16;

float widthOfTextView = textView.textContainer.size.width - horizontalPadding;
float height = [string sizeWithFont:textView.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(widthOfTextView, 999999.0f) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height + verticalPadding;

return height;
}

- (CGSize)text: (NSString *)text sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size {
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7")) {
    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
    CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:size options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:attributesDictionary context:nil];

    return frame.size;
}
else {
    return [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:size];
   }
}
```

It load fine when i run it initially but when i scroll down and back up, the `UITextView` became a vertical single line column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think the this might be the cause:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You are using a `dequeued` cell's text view to determine the height of the cell. However the `dequeued` cell may not having any text data (or different text) in it, plus the `commentView` is `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`, the width calculated by

```
float widthOfTextView = textView.textContainer.size.width - horizontalPadding;
```

may be very small under the scenario of scroll down and backup.

Comment: Hi, i changed the height for `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and the same issue occurs. I tried and i found out that it is the `[cell.commentTextView sizeToFit]` is the issue..